# how to connect to an SQL Server sitting in some other domain than your using its port number?

Tags: sql-server

unable to connect to an SQL Server though I know its domain address, port number, user id and password.

Eg:: 
`Domain: [systemName].[Domain].[companyName]`

```
UserId: user1, password: password1 and portNumber: 1234.
```

when tried connecting using Management studio, I couldn't find where to enter port number in the login screen.

[image]

please share the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering 
`abc,1234`
in the server name box

Answer (score 0):

you have to user server name is your ip address of database with port number

like :

server name : 192.xxx.xx.xxx:80
username :abc

passwword:###

Authentication : sql server authentication